# How to integrate soapUI(Free Version) report(.html report) into sonarqube 5.6

Tags: soapui, sonarqube5.6, easyhtmlreport

What type of configuration we need to do to show generated html soapui report into sonarqube 5.6

Comment: Sonar Quebe is not there. But, you can check [it](https://hub.docker.com/r/nmrao/soapui/) to generate html report.

Comment: @Rao can we convert soapui html report into code coverage and then display it on sonar dashboard?

Comment: No voice in sonar quebe.

Comment: Ok. Thank You for your response.